# Unable to call controller action from a partial view rendered via ajax

Tags: model-view-controller, view, controller, partial

i have the following set up :

A) HTML div container in Parent View to hold partial view returned:

```
<div id="divProjectCostList" class="tablecontainer">

</div>
```

B) Controller method that returns the view model -

```
    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult GetProjectCostsById(int viewProjectId)
    {
        return PartialView("ProjectCost", GetProjectCostsViewModel(viewProjectId));  
    }
```

C) AJAX to render the partial view HTML into the div above -

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".retProjTran").click(function () {

        var projectid = $(this).data("projectid");

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            asynch: true,
            type: "GET",
            url: "@(Url.Action("GetProjectCostsById", "Project"))",
            data: { "viewProjectId": projectid },
            success: function (retData) {
                $('#divProjectCostList').html(retData);
            }
        })
    });
})
```

The above works just fine.

the Partial view set up in order to get elements from the returned model and render these in a table

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ProjectCostList", "Project", FormMethod.Get))
{
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ProjectCostType)</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink(item.ProjectCostType.ToString(), "", null,
                     new { @class = "retProjDetails", data_details = item.ProjectCostId })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
}
```

This Partial view also needs to access a JS method  -

```
$(".retProjDetails").click(function () {


        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            asynch: true,
            type: "GET",
            url: "@(Url.Action("GetProjectCostDetails", "Project"))",
            data: { "viewProjectCostId": projectCostId },
            success: function (retData) {
            $('#divProjectCostList').html(retData);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        })
    });
```

I can see the JS function being called from the rendered Actionlink, however the relevant Controller action is simply not hit..

I'd imagine this is some sort of issue with how I am rendering the Partial, but cannot figure out what. Hope someone can provide a clue. Happy for any suggestions on whether this set up is optimal or I need to change..

Comment: take look http://www.olivieralbertini.com/Tutorial/asp-net-mvc-partial-view-action-invoker-jquery-ui-ajax. It's a tutorial with a demo. I hope that will help you

Answer (score 0):

You simply change your

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ProjectCostList", "Project", FormMethod.Get))
```

to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ProjectCostList", "Project", FormMethod.Post))
```

in the Partial View and things will be fine.

Comment: But the method is specified to be a get. How does changing to post fixes it? Need to know! :D